# Does this functional equation have a solution (also is there free functional equation solving software)?

Tags: functional-equations, math-software

I tried typing this into Wolfram and it couldn't solve it, despite it looking simple:

$f(x) = (1/2)f(x)^2.$

Does this have a non-constant solution? (initial values not yet determined)

Comment: Functional equations are horrendously difficult to solve, so I doubt that there is free or even paid software to do this in general.

Comment: That's just an algebraic equation for $f$. A solution is any function with values in the set $\{0,2\}$.

Comment: Unless there is a typo in the problem this one is very easy to solve - put for $f$ any function which takes values $0$ or $2$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Why resort to software, though? The functional notation is confusing you. Instead of $f(x)$ just use e.g $z$. We have the equation
$$z=\frac{z^2}{2}$$
The only solutions for this are $z=0$ and $z=2$. This means the only possible solutions for $f$ are
$$f:x\mapsto 0 \\ f:x\mapsto 2$$
Good luck finding a non-constant solution, because they don't exist.

**EDIT:** I spoke to soon. If $f$ attains only the values $0$ or $2$ it will work. E.g,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x< 0\\
2 & x\geq 0
\end{cases}$$
Works.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards